# Could anyone provide me with derivation for planar moment of inertia? I also have a couple of aditional doubts

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I've been searching for the derivation of planar moment of inertial but I can't find it anywhere $(I = \iint y^2dA)$. I don't understand why there's a $y^2$ term in there but I do understand that you divide up the body into smaller parts which is why you integrate over the entire body. I also can't understand how they related this formula to inertia but I guess this part of the derivation, it still feels so abstract.
I just have a couple of additional questions, is the same derivation or the same thought applicable to other types of inertia as well and what does $I_{xx}$, $I_{yy}$ and $I_{xy}$ exactly mean? Is it just MOI about the $x$ axis, $y$ axis and $x-y$ axis?

Comment: You might need to split this up. When you ask multiple questions, a complete answer requires a treatise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's experimentally obvious that the effort it takes to bend a beam or plate scales up far faster than its thickness. The thickness of an aluminum aircraft skin is only a hundred times thicker than aluminum foil, which I can deflect by blowing on it!

I like to think of the relationship (which is in fact cubic) arising through three effects, one for each degree of linear scaling:

1. When we bend something, tension arises on the outside and compression on the inside, with no stress at the effective center—the so-called neutral axis. The simplest compatible model has the stress scaling linearly with the distance $y$ from the neutral axis. There's one $y$.
2. That stress is equivalent to a force applied over a narrow strip a certain distance $y$ from the neutral axis. In turn, that force can be thought of as exerting a moment around the neutral axis that resists further bending. The lever arm $y$ of that moment provides the second $y$.
3. The material isn't free to rearrange or slide (as an unglued stack of thin films would); each small region operates in conjunction with the others to resist additional bending. So we integrate $y^2$ over the cross-sectional area, which gives a $y^3$ term (in addition to a linear term for the width). Thus, the planar moment of inertia for a rectangular cross section scales with $bh^3$, where $b$ is the width (or base) and $h$ is the thickness (or height).

Yes, you are interpreting $I_{xx}$, $I_{yy}$, and $I_{xy}$ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia (or rotational inertia) of a planer object relative to an axis of rotation  perpendicular to the plane, is the (double) integral of $r^2$(dm), where r is measured from the (dm) to the axis.  The (dm) is (M/A)(dA)  and the (dA) = (dx)(dy) or r(dθ)(dr).  This can be extended to a 3D object with a triple integral. The r is measured perpendicular to the axis of rotation with (dm) = (M/V)(dV).  The (dV) might be expressed in rectangular, cylindrical, or spherical coordinates. Inertia is usually associated with momentum; (mv) for linear momentum or (Iω) for angular momentum.

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax.